# File Upload using Drupal 8 Rest API but getting boundary error in Postman

Tags: rest, file-upload, drupal, drupal-8

Can you please let me know how can I upload any type of file from Drupal Rest API? I am using OAuth2 for Authorization but getting Boundary error when I am uploading file from Postman. 
Any help please?

getting below error in Postman

```
{
    "message": "No route found that matches \"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------845557214163009053020500\""
}
```

Comment: For me, clearing the cache got rid of the error.